# ipython javascript not updating text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipython

This seems to work as a plain html/javascript file opened in a browser but when I put it in an IPython notebook only the button text is updating (the paragraph text does not update). What could be causing this?

IPython notebook cell code:
    from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display

```
display(HTML("""
<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
<button id="something">Try it</button>
"""))
js = """
$("#something").click(function() {
$('#demo').text("Changed text");
$('#something').text('Change button');
});
"""
js = Javascript(js)
display(js)
```

Plain html/javascript:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
<button id="something">Try it</button>
<script>
$("#something").click(function() {
$('#demo').text("Changed text");
$('#something').text('Change button');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap jquery code inside document.ready().

Comment: @Kartikeya that should not be necessary; the code follows the DOM elements it affects. (Maybe ipython is weird?)

Comment: Also jQuery 1.3 is very old.

Comment: yes agree with Pointy 1.3 version is too old just upgrade jquery version.

Comment: I am only using the old jquery in the pure (non-IPython) version and that *does* work. So that should not be the issue.

Comment: @Kartikeya ... posted your solution as an answer below. Feel free to copy/paste and I'll mark as correct if you care about points. Also, how did you know this solution? IPython oddity?

Comment: i m just here to help others not for personnal glory(i don't want to put a answer here) .. i m glad that your problem solved and don't forget to mark your answer as accepted so that accepted answer help others also..and i don't know ipython a lot just read about this problem somewhere and posted comment here...thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Kartikeya suggestion worked:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, Javascript, display

display(HTML("""
<p id="demo">A Paragraph.</p>
<button id="something">Try it</button>
"""))
js = """
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("#something").click(function() {
        $('#demo').text("Changed text");
        $('#something').text('Change button');
        });
    });
"""
js = Javascript(js)
display(js)
```